# Reading python ttk Styles from configuration file

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, ttk, configparser

Using python ttk and the ConfigParser leads me to the following issue.

I want to use a Configuration File to make Styles adaptable during usage for every user - not only the ones with access to the sources.

Using the ttk-styles inside my python script (Python 2.7) from hardcoded sections work like a charm

```
def LoadStyles(self):
  s=ttk.Style()

  if not os.path.exists("Styles.cfg"):
     s.configure('TFrame', background='white')
     s.configure('Dark.TFrame', background='#292929')
  else:
     config=ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
     config.read("Styles.cfg")

     for section in config.sections():
        for (key, val) in config.items(section):
           try:
              s.configure(section, key="%s"%val)
           except:
              print("Error Parsing Styles Config File:  [%s].%s = %s"%(section, key, val))
```

Using the Configuration File (contents below) results in white backgrounds for all Frames, also the ones that are declared like

```
self.loginFrame=ttk.Frame(self, style='Dark.TFrame')
```

**EDIT:** they are not white but non-filled (default fill) .

The styling is both ways done before the widgets are loaded, either hardcoded or by config file.

I just don't get where i am stuck in here, manuals and SO Search just did not give me any answers on that one...

```
[TFrame]
background = "white"
[Dark.TFrame]
background = "#292929"
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution:

The issue was that "key" was written as keyword into the style.
e.g. 
`{'key': '#292929'}` 
This data could be read using

```
print(s.configure(section))
```

after the

```
s.configure(section, key="%s"%val)
```

Keyword unpacking was the clue:
(Thanks a lot to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976658/most-pythonic-way-of-assigning-keyword-arguments-using-a-variable-as-keyword) )

```
for section in config.sections():
    for (key, val) in config.items(section):
        try:
            test={ "%s" % key : "%s" % val }
            s.configure(section, **test)
        except:
            print("Error Parsing Styles Config File:")
            print("   [%s].%s = %s"%(section, key, val))
```

Now also the Styles read from the Configuration File can be used.