# How to pass keyword argument as a key to other function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
def edit_properties(self, device, ssc_command="hexa", value="test")
    result = self.edit_devices.edit_device_property(device, ssc_command=value)
```

I want to pass "ssc_command" as a key to self.edit_devices.edit_device_property(device, ssc_command=value) and value as a value.

Comment: Can you give an example of how `edit_properties` might be called, and what you would expect from that call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most pythonic way of assigning keyword arguments using a variable as keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976658/most-pythonic-way-of-assigning-keyword-arguments-using-a-variable-as-keyword)

Comment: @ScottHunter I got it ...It's not possible to pass as i asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary/kwargs expansion. First, you make a dict with `ssc_command` as the key and `value` as the value, and then you use `**` to expand it into a set of keyword arguments:

```
result = self.edit_device.edit_device_property(device, **{ssc_command:value})
```