# Flask/Jinja: Is there a way to use a Jinja variable as a parameter name in a Python call?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have the following in an HTML file:

```html
{% for ctype in course.sections %}
    {% for instr in course.instructors[ctype] %}
        ...
        <a class="dropdown-item"
           href="{{ url_for(
                            'views.get_results',
                            user=current_user,
                            user_query=userQuery,
                            ctype=instr
                           ) }}">
        {{ instr }}
        </a>
        ...
```

where I am populating a dropdown menus in various parts of the page (see image), and would like to use `ctype` (as set in the outer loop) as the parameter name (e.g., `REC=Aghli,+Sina`). Essentially, I am trying to find the syntactically correct equivalent of

```py
url_for('views.get_results',
        user=current_user,
        user_query=userQuery,
        {{ctype}}=instr
        )
```

Note that `instr` seems to be pulling its value from the for-loop already, so I'm not sure how to tell Jinja that I want to use a templated variable as the parameter name as well. Currently, I am getting a url like `...ctype=Ashli,+Sina...` (just passing the parameter named `ctype` verbatim). Thank you for any help - please let me know if I can clarify anything!
[image]

Comment: if i understood correctly, you can use in the url_for arguments: `course_type=ctype, instructor=instr`, i.e. fixed variable names and depending on the `course_type`'s value, the `get_results` will do the appropriate processing.

Comment: you should send `ctype` as value, not variable's name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I see that this is probably the better approach, however, I am still curious if one can dynamically name a field through Jinja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this all boils down to [*"Is it possible to pass a keyword argument where the keyword is a variable to a function in Python?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976658/most-pythonic-way-of-assigning-keyword-arguments-using-a-variable-as-keyword), the answer is basically the same: yes, using a dictionary and passing it with `**dict`.

So in your case, you could do:

```
url_for(
  'views.get_results',
  **{
    'user': current_user,
    'user_query': userQuery,
    ctype: instr
  }
)
```